# Get values from SQL table along with column name as list in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pymssql

I have a SQL table like below

```
----------------------------------
     Key         |    Value
----------------------------------
Ralph Williams      Football
Michael Tippett     Basketball
Edward Elgar        Baseball
Rebecca Clarke      Netball
Ethel Smyth         Badminton
```

I have used `cursor.execute("select top 5 Key, Value from TestTable")` and then tried to convert as list  using `mylist = list(cursor)`

But I am getting like

```
[(u'Ralph Williams', u'Football'), (u'Michael Tippett', u'Basketball'), (u'Edward Elgar', u'Baseball'), (u'Rebecca Clarke', u'Netball'), (u'Ethel Smyth', u'Rugby')]
```

But I need this table as list in python like below

```
[{'Key':'Ralph Williams', 'Value':'Football'}, {'Key':'Michael Tippett', 'Value':'Basketball'}, {'Key':'Edward Elgar', 'Value':'Baseball'}, {'Key':'Rebecca Clarke', 'Value':'Netball'}, {'Key':'Ethel Smyth', 'Value':'Rugby'}]
```

How can I make that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a dict cursor - see the [pymssql docs](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html#rows-as-dictionaries).

```
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Key_value_pair = dict(list_of_tuple_from_the_database)
```